# How to avoid multiple nesting levels in iOS programming

Tags: ios, objective-c

How avoid below code in iOS programming

```
                }];
            }];
        }];
    });
```

Here is one scenario in my code:

```
(void)my_function {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSManagedObjectContext *childContext = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType] autorelease];
        childContext.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext;
        [childContext performBlock:^{
            [self.operationManager POST:URL parameters:nil block:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                //Do something
                [childContext performBlock:^{
                    //Do something
                }];
            }];
        }];
    });
}
```

Why I ask this question:

1. Readability
2. In the scenario I mentioned above, I'm not sure whether I'm coding in a right way, since it looks ugly and it's hard to maintain.

Comment: Use fewer nested blocks? What's the issue? Why do you want to avoid multiple levels of nesting?

Comment: I agree with @rmaddy, I see no reason to want to limit this. In fact being able to do this makes programming easier.

Comment: Using blocks with asynchronous code tends to lead to needed a few nested blocks. There's little you can do about it.

Comment: I think it is just fine to read, and in Xcode if a block is finished and needs no more attention, you can click the colored bar to the left of the code and collapse the block making the code easier to read.

Comment: Maybe consider using a framework such as [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa).

Comment: Take a look at [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit)

Comment: Does this compile? Shouldn't the dispatch_async statement end with "});" instead of "}];"?

Comment: @rmaddy Multiple levels of nesting can become really confusing when you are reading code. Nodejs has multiple libraries to organize asynchronous code and it sure does help when reading js. BTW, congrats on cracking 100k and helping the community so much.

Comment: @JoeSmith sorry for the typo, corrected

Answer (score 1):

When possible (i.e. when your blocks don't have dependency on the context or local variable where they are used), you can declare your blocks outside of your function or at the beginning of your function, store them in a variable, and then use them by their name when needed.

You will avoid some nesting because all you begin/end block brackets will be at the same level.

```
(void)my_function {
    NSManagedObjectContext *childContext = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]
        initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType] autorelease];
    childContext.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    void (^block4)(void) = ^{ /* Do something */ };

    void (^block3)(void) = ^{ /* Do something; */
                              [childContext performBlock:block4]; };

    void (^networkBlock2)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) = void (^){
        [self.operationManager POST:URL 
                         parameters:nil 
                              block:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                block3; } };

    dispatch_block_t block1 = ^{ [childContext performBlock:networkBlock2]; };

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block1);
}
```

That is the idea. You have to be careful about the scope of your captured variables and context, and see (in this case) if the NSManagedObjectContext can be instantiated when you declare your blocks rather than when you execute the first one (block1) on the main queue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with (*for this particular example*):

```
- (void)my_function { // I'd use camelCase
    [self.operationManager POST:URL parameters:nil block:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *childContext = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType] autorelease]; // autorelease is gone with ARC
        childContext.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext;
        [childContext performBlock:^{
            // Do something
        }];
    }];
}
```

**OR**

```
- (void)my_function { // I'd use camelCase
    [self.operationManager POST:URL parameters:nil block:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [self another_function:responseObject];

        // Uncomment if you really need to use the main thread
        //[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(another_function:) withObject:responseObject waitUntilDone:NO];
    }];
}

- (void)another_function:(id)responseObject { // I'd use camelCase
    NSManagedObjectContext *childContext = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType] autorelease]; // autorelease is gone with ARC
    childContext.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    [childContext performBlock:^{
        // Do something with the 'responseObject'
    }];
}
```

Dropped "dispatch_get_main_queue()" - I think you don't have to be on the main thread to use the main-thread context, you have to be on the main thread if you want to perform actions in Core Data.

Extracted self.operationManager's POST since it doesn't have to be inside a context's performBlock.

Then do whatever you need to do inside the block of the self.operationManager.

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to discuss whether such code is readable or not. I think it is a question of getting familiar with blocks.

However, sometimes you want to re-linearize code execution, because nested blocks in your code are executed one after one. If you have a synchronous twin of the method expecting a block parameter, simply use that. If there is none, you can build it your own.

Let's have the asynchronous version of a method:

```
@interface MyClass : …
- (void)doSomethingInBackgroundCompletion:…;
@end
```

With the typical usage:

```
…
[receiver doSomethingInBackgroundCompletion:
^(id result)
{
  // Do Something with result 
  …
}
…
```

You can linearize it with semaphores. Simply at a synchronous version in a category:

```
@interface MyClass (Linearization)
- (id)doSomethingInBackgroundAndWait;
@end

@implementation MyClass (Linearization)
- (id)doeSomethingInBackgroundAndWait
{
  dispatch_semaphore_t done = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
  __block id finally;  
  [receiver doSomethingInBackgroundCompletion:
  ^(id result)
  {
     finally = result;
     dispatch_semaphore_signal(done);
  }
  dispatch_semaphore_wait(done);
  dispatch_semaphore_release(done);

  return result;
}
@end
```

Now you can use that method synchronous:

```
…
id result = [receiver doSomethingInBackgroundAndWait];
// Do Something with result 
…
```

I do *not* say that this should be a common pattern. In most cases getting familiar with blocks is the better way.